# Nginx does not listen to port 3000

Tags: node.js, nginx, npm, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt app and I try to config Nginx ,  when I use `curl localhost:3000` I can see my website tag and status 200 , but I can not open my website with domain name , it's take to load for like 2 minutes and then it will show me " This site can’t be reached "  I made an error log and this was in error log

```
[error] 72792#72792: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.68.50.201, server: domain.com , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "domain.com"
```

I try this command `netstat -tulpn` to make sure nginx is listening . and here is the result

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      70267/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      72791/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      773/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      773/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      72791/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61184/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      689/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      72791/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      72791/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      689/sshd: /usr/sbin
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           61184/systemd-resol
```

this is my nginx config

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl ;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        root /path/to/my/front-app;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/nuxt.error.log;


        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
        server {
                 listen 80;
                 listen [::]:80;
                  server_name myServerIp;
                 return 301 $https://myServerDomain;
                }
```

Comment: How do you run your nuxt app? It looks like your app refuses the proxied connection from Nginx.

Comment: @Spirit I tried once with  pm2 start "node .output/server/index.mjs"   and once without  pm2 just node .output/server/index.mjs

Comment: I have researched nuxt a bit, but I come to the conclusion, that I have too little knowledge about nuxt. I would change the proxy link from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`, but I am unable to provide more help, SRY.

Comment: @Spirit thanks alot mate for you'r time i changed proxy_pass to `localhost:3000` , `127.0.0.1:3000` , `myIP:3000` and still noting :( i spend a week and still couldnt fix it :(((

Comment: when you say "with domain name" does that mean you are running your website on a remote machine or your local machine? Is that domain name pointing to the correct IP? Is the machine configured correctly to allow connections from outside? Did you try serving a simple plain `index.html` from your nginx to see if that's working?

Comment: @derpirscher yes i have a domain name and 2 separate ngingx config , one for back-end and one for front-end , my back-end work correctly , for test i made a test.html and it's work , after that I start my nuxt app with `npm run dev ` it's work ,  not correctly , but it's show me my pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write an answer here mainly because I will feel too limited in a comment regarding layout/presentation. Please don't take it as a definite answer per se.
(also, OP reached out directly to me hence my effort here)

First, I would start by migrating to the latest version of Nuxt (`v3.0 stable`) rather than an RC. So that way, you're on the latest and greatest.
Then, I'll double-check that I'm using Node v18 because this is the LTS and you should use the LTS.
I'll start debugging the app locally, hence `yarn build && yarn preview`. If that works well, then the issue is probably not coming from Nuxt.
(I also recommend yarn or PNPM as package managers rather than npm because of speed + error explicitness when installing any NPM packages)

---

You can then try to host your app on a Node.js-powered PASS like Render.com or Heroku. That way, you leave the configuration of the VPS to somebody else to manage and focus primarily on your app. Follow the official guides [available here](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/render).
If that works, then it's definitely not a Nuxt issue.

I'm a bit rusty on the Nginx part, so I'm not sure to help quickly with that part as I used to.
My main question here is, "Do you really need to manage your own server?"
If not, then you could focus on the code itself and let the deployment part aside, especially if is taking 2 weeks of your time and not bringing a lot of value.

If it is something that you truly care about, then the first step would be to double-check some of those points:

- try to expose a simple `.html` file to your domain name, access it from `www.yourcoolwebsite.com`
- try to expose a Node.js app, and render a `view` to double-check the Node.js part
- if the 2 above work well, your Nuxt app should be working totally fine too!

---

Here you're trying to achieve too many things at the same time, you need to proceed by elimination and debug with what you know/are not sure of.
Fixing an issue with various variables without isolation is too time-consuming and not efficient.

Comment: thank you so much Kissu u fixed my problem i change Nuxt version from 3.0.0-rc.12 to 3.0.0 stable and upgrade node version from 16 to 18 and boom my problem fixed after 2 weeks 
about buying host from another country , I cant , because i live in Iran and we are not connect to global bank so can not transfer money . so i have to configure my own server as Devops and also be a Programmer  , thanks you so much mate